# How to print in a specific place in an HTML code?

Tags: php

I have a PHP code like this:

```
<?php
  if($condition) {myFunction();};
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
Some HTML code
<?php
  function myFunction() {
     print "Print some new code";  
  };
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When the myFunction is called, the new code is printed before the first html tag.

 How can I change that behaviour and print, say, after "Some HTML code".

Thanks!

Comment: The part that is calling it is at the top, whereas the function to call is where you want your 'if' statement to be.

Comment: Hi, guys! Thanks! But what if I want to print from the code that is calling, in different places on the page. Is that possible?

Comment: <? myFunction(); ?> Add that to the page, wherever you want the writing to go ;)

Comment: Thanks, Lucas. I meant what Musa had answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the function where you want to print not define it there.

```
<?php
  function myFunction() {
     print "Print some new code";  
  };
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
Some HTML code
<?php
  if($condition) {myFunction();};
?>
</body>
</html>
```

--EDIT--
for comment

Check the conditions in both places, or separate your logic and content

```
<?php
  function myFunction() {
     return "Print some new code";  
  }
  $somecontent = '';
  $morecontent = '';
  if($condition) {
      $somecontent = myFunction();
  }
  else{
      $morecontent = 'some more content';
  }
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
<?php
    echo $morecontent;
?>
Some HTML code
<?php
    echo $somecontent;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Musa! Thanks for the help. I understand what you mean, but if a condition has to be checked in one place, and depending on the outcome different functions are called, which need to print in different places. Say, at one outcome one function prints at the top of the page, at another outcome the other function prints at the bottom?

Comment: Oh! Thanks a LOT, Musa! That is what I meant!

Answer (score 2):

The function is being run when the statement returns true, so it does print "Print some new code"; right there.

In order to get the new code within the body tag, have the if statement in there.

As well, If you move the function outside of the rendered HTML (like below) then it keeps the markup separate from the logic.

```
<?php
function myFunction() {
  print "Print some new code";  
};
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Some HTML code
    <?php
      if($condition) {myFunction();};
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things you should remember for working with functions.

1- Define it first

```
<?php
    function function_name () {
       // do something
    }
```

2- Call it secondly

```
function_name();
```

And remember function will return whatever it has where you'll call it, not where you have defined it. So in your case as you've inverted the game the result is inverted.

Here is the remedy:

```
<?php
  function myFunction() {
    return "Print some new code";  
};
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
Some HTML code
<?php

if ($condition) {
    echo myFunction();
}

</body>
</html>
```